# Can not register handler for SIGTRAP

Tags: c, linux, signals

I am trying to register a handler for the `SIGTRAP` caused by calling `int3` in child, but it does not work. Changing `SIGTRAP` to `SIGCHLD` works.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void child();
void parent(pid_t pid);
void sigtrap_handler(int sig);

int main(){
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        child();
    } else {
        parent(pid);
    }
}


void child(){
    sleep(1);
    asm("int3");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void parent(pid_t pid){
    signal(SIGTRAP, sigtrap_handler);
    int status;
    do{
        waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
    } while(!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void sigtrap_handler(int sig){
    printf("Process %d received sigtrap %d.\n", getpid(), sig);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the parent process has registered a signal handler for `SIGTRAP` but not the child process. So when you raise `SIGTRAP` in child process, the parent process process is not aware of it.

`SIGCHLD` works (i.e. received by parent) because when the child process terminates (or stops), the signal `SIGCHLD` is sent to the parent process. But in case of `SIGTRAP` (or any other signal), it's not sent to the parent process. `SIGCHLD` is special in the sense, it's sent by default to the parent process on termination whereas other signals are not.

If you add a handler in child process, you'll see the handler getting invoked:

```
void child(){
    signal(SIGTRAP, sigtrap_handler);
    sleep(1);
    asm("int3");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

By the way, `printf()` is not an [async-signal-safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) function, so you can't safely call it in a signal handler.